# Flask uWSGI prevent sequencing of requests

Tags: python, flask, concurrency, locking, uwsgi

I have a Flask API with an endpoint that has a problem: one user should send only one request for some period of time.
In pseudocode it looks like the following:

```py
session_id = user.get('current_session_id')
current_session = get_current_session(session_id)
secret_variable = current_session.get('secret_variable')

if secret_variable:
    return {'error': 'user already has secret variable'}

secret_variable = perform_secret_request()  # this one is time consuming, so user shouldn't run many of them
current_session.add_values({'secret_variable': secret_variable})  # later variable will be removed from the session, but it doesn't matter here
```

I've tried uwsgi.lock() for this purpose, but it works only for one process with one thread. When I  increase the number of threads or/and processes it stops working.
Example within pseudocode:

```py
session_id = user.get('current_session_id')
current_session = get_current_session(session_id)

uwsgi.lock()
secret_variable = current_session.get('secret_variable')
uwsgi.unlock()

if secret_variable:
    return {'error': 'user already has secret variable'}

secret_variable = perform_secret_request()  # this one is time consuming, so user shouldn't run many of them
current_session.add_values({'secret_variable': secret_variable})  # later variable will be removed from the session, but it doesn't matter here
```

How I can lock this problem part? Are there any alternative solutions?